# delete an example from dataframe pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop-down-menu, delete-row

i have a dataframe like this

```
     Phrase                          Sentiment

   [ good , movie ]                   positive

   [wooow ,is , it ,very, good  ]   positive

      []                             negative
      []                              pOSTIVE
```

the column Phrase type is object  and  need to delete the rows containing []
and i don't know ho do it using python

like this:

```
 Phrase                          Sentiment

   [ good , movie ]                   positive

   [wooow ,is , it ,very, good  ]   positive
```

Comment: @MYGz YES EXACTLY

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the presence of empty lists by `str.len()==0` and filter the `DF` based on this by performing a negation operation.

```
df[df.Phrase.str.len() != 0]
```

[image]

To know the rows where empty lists are present:

```
df.Phrase.str.len() == 0

0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
Name: Phrase, dtype: bool
```

---

Incase there are empty strings present, their length would also equate to zero. In this case, filtering on the basis of their type would be helpful by using a custom function on `map`.

```
df[df.Phrase.map(lambda x: len(x) if isinstance(x, list) else None) != 0]
```

---

If they are string representation of lists, then you could filter directly on them to get the subsetted `DF`:

```
df[df.Phrase != "[]"]
```

Comment: It doesn't seems a valid list to me. Might be OP forgot to put quotes or it's a string. Update for string as well.

Answer (score 3):

empty lists `[]` evaluate to `False`

```
df[df.Phrase.astype(bool)]

                       Phrase Sentiment
0               [good, movie]  positive
1  [woow, is, it, very, good]  positive
```

---

***setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [['good', 'movie'], 'positive'],
        [['woow', 'is', 'it', 'very', 'good'], 'positive'],
        [[], 'negative'],
        [[], 'pOSITIVE']
    ], columns=['Phrase', 'Sentiment'])
```